# Android Application - The width of my spinners change when I select a value

Tags: android, user-interface, android-spinner

I am developing a simple application which is supposed to demonstrate a simple web-shop scenario. In the app I have one spinner for the item, one for the amount of items, and then a textview displaying the total sum.

Theese threee objects are displayed in a row, according to this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100" 
    android:layout_below="@id/connection"
    android:id="@+id/row1">

    <Spinner 
        android:layout_width="0dp" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/vara1"
        android:layout_weight="51"
        android:layout_gravity="left"/>


    <Spinner 
        android:layout_width="0dp" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:id="@+id/antal1"
        android:layout_weight="25"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>


    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="0dp" 
        android:text="@string/text_nolltotal" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
        android:id="@+id/pris1"  
        android:textColor="#FF000000"
        android:layout_weight="24"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now, when I select an item in my spinner, the width of the spinner changes, which breaks the design.

This only happens when I am using a wider screen, when I try it on certain devices it's fine. Also, on wider devices, a gap are created between the second spinner and the textview.

Any idea as to what may cause this?

Comment: Width changes when you select an item or it changes without selecting the item?

Comment: Give " android:layout_width" of every widget to "Wrap content" the design will not affect..

Comment: @Droid The width changes when I select an item, the empty boxes are a little bit smaller.

Answer (score 0):

*use this code it may help you*

```
<LinearLayout
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100" 

    android:id="@+id/row1">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="51" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/antal1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="25" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pris1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="24"
        android:gravity="bottom"         
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#FF000000" />

</LinearLayout>
```